# Values of different ID's at same timestamp

Tags: r, dataframe, timestamp

I want to create a data frame with different ID's value at same time interval and if the value is not present,I have to carry the last value of that particular ID.Here is my data frame

```
 df
  ID                FROM                  TO    VALUE
1  a 2014-09-24 20:00:52    2014-09-24 20:00:52 121.9000
2  a 2014-09-24 20:02:38    2014-09-24 20:02:39 111.9000
3  a 2014-09-24 20:13:46    2014-09-24 20:13:48 120.9000
4  b 2014-09-24 20:00:52    2014-09-24 20:00:52 113.5631
5  b 2014-09-24 20:02:38    2014-09-24 20:02:38 112.5631
6  b 2014-09-24 20:13:39    2014-09-24 20:13:49 110.5631
```

Value of a was 111.9000 from 2014-09-24 20:02:38 to 2014-09-24 20:02:39. I want to have the output of above df as

```
a           b               FROM             TO
121.9000    113.5631    2014-09-24 20:00:52  2014-09-24 20:00:52
111.9000    112.5631    2014-09-24 20:02:38  2014-09-24 20:02:38  
111.9000    110.5631    2014-09-24 20:13:39  2014-09-24 20:13:45 # a's value is carry forward
120.9000    110.5631    2014-09-24 20:13:46  2014-09-24 20:13:49
```

Any efficient way to achieve above result.Thanks.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), FROM = c("2014-09-24 20:00:52", 
"2014-09-24 20:02:38", "2014-09-24 20:13:46", "2014-09-24 20:00:52", 
"2014-09-24 20:02:38", "2014-09-24 20:13:39"), TO = c("2014-09-24 20:00:52", 
"2014-09-24 20:02:39", "2014-09-24 20:13:48", "2014-09-24 20:00:52", 
"2014-09-24 20:02:38", "2014-09-24 20:13:49"), VALUE = c(121.899978637695, 
111.899978637695, 120.899978637695, 113.563064575195, 112.563064575195, 
110.563064575195)), .Names = c("ID", "FROM", "TO", "VALUE"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is a bit worn out, but, what have you tried?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have tried with intersect which is quite wrong then i have tried with for loop which is quite inefficient.

Comment: Consider documenting your effort.

Comment: I am confused with the expected outcome. Why do you expect 4 rows in the end? I think there are five unique combinations of FROM & TO.`20:02:38 (FROM)20:02:39(TO)` seems to be missing. I think you also have typos in the expected outcome. For example, `2014-09-24 20:13:45` does not exist in TO.

Comment: zoo::na.locf    Last Observation Carried Forward